# A 80's comic could be late 70's book I read as a kid

Tags: story-identification, books, space, cartoon

I don't remember much about it but I thought it was very cool and strange back in the day.

The details I remember is that it started of with a guy (human) in a funny looking spaceship.  It was made up of 3 or four spheres connected together. I seem to recall he crash landed on a unknown planet.

The second thing I remember is he met a sexy looking woman and saved here from some robot guards with big smiling faces. On the planet they where they found some strange looking SlotMachines robots.

This is what I can recall for now.

The comic book was a bit under A3 format and I seem to recall it was in color and black & white every other page.

I have drawn a crude depiction of the guard robots:
[image]

The drawings of the man and the woman was realistic to a human body and in color. Actually very nice artwork. I'm pretty sure it was a book with a hard cover.
From what I can recall it would seem that this is a one story kind of deal and not a series, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "SlotMachine robot"?

Comment: If you think of a normal slot machine(like in Vegas) as hes body and put a head on top and arms on the side and legs under it

Comment: This is the sort of story found in _Heavy Metal_ or _Epic Illustrated_ back in 1980's.  Semi-nude women wandering around on spaceships or blasted landscapes pursued by or mating with monsters and robots.  Popular stories often ended up in hardback reprints.

Comment: @Kyle Jones  This sounds like exactly what it is, the hot semi nude woman and they where nude at some point I think. I was around 7years old when reading/looking at the pictures. I'm Norwegian and did not read English back then. But I think your on to something.

Comment: If you ever come back and have that old drawing, feel free to [edit] it back it. It seemed to help the people answer it, and I'm curious to see it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recognize the plotlines you mentioned but they sound (brilliantly) dumb enough to have been from [Red Dwarf](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/news/index.cfm). In some seasons (series) of the show, the crew used the *Starbug*, actually a shuttlecraft from their original ship:

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf#Magazine), there was a fan magazine, the *Red Dwarf Smegazine*, including comic strips, published between 1992 and 1994.

Comment: The *Starbug* was the very first thing that popped into mind when I saw the OP's drawing.

Comment: @The Photon it is not Red Dwarf, thanks for trying tho :)

Comment: And Red Dwarf never had nude women.

Comment: @MrLister, OP never said "nude" women until much later.

Comment: I have looked through all issues of HeavyMetal 70's and 80's have not seen the one I'm looking fore. There where some resemblance in art style so it could be likely that one of the artist's in heavy metal magazine has drawn the story I'm looking fore.